# How to open Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-express

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, and now I want to start it. I expected I could just go to Metro and type, but nothing (relevant) comes up! I tried to find the installation folder but can't find it. There are a few versions of Visual Studio but none of them say "Express 2013". Despite how I sound, I'm not a complete idiot when it comes to computers, but I just can't seem to open Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, well, the C++ IDE anyway. I have read the official "Getting Started" guides but they don't tell me how to actually open it! Why can't it be as easy as opening IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm?

Comment: "devenv.exe" used to be the executable.

Comment: Have you tried searching in the start menu for "Microsoft"?

Comment: @Dima Maligin, yes I have, I get a bunch of MS Office tools, and Microsoft Clip Organiser. I've also searched for "Express C++", and whatever sensible things one may think of.

Comment: @Ray I assume you tried searching for "Visual" as well. The installetion should be in Program Files.

Comment: @Ray also you can try opening a VS project by double clicking an *.sln file it should open it in VS, and make sure the VS installetion didn't fail!

Comment: I don't have an .sln file to hand, but I suppose I could go and find one. I've tried all the obvious things you may think of (except opening an .sln file). But surely I shouldn't have to find an .sln file just to open the VS IDE!?

Comment: @Ray are you sure the VS installetion didn't fail?

Comment: Yes, sorry I figured it out. You can't search "Visual Studio", you must search "VS". Thank you very much for your help and concern though. If you live in London I'll buy you a pint.

Comment: Are these instructions for Windows 8 helpful? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO1IZda0CSE

Comment: I had the same problem. Ridiculous.

Comment: @Ray, we also search with "VS Express"

Comment: I was facing same problem and solved like this. you can search by pressing window key and then type visual studio it will show the visual studio version that you recently install. right click on it. open the file location then double click on the vs express 2013 for web.

Comment: I don't understand how a Visual Studio question can be "off-topic". Anyway, since I can't post a proper answer, here goes: I had luck running the `.exe` directly from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Ok for all who have trouble opening VS you can do it like so:
In the search area of Start type `run` and in the run window type `devenv`.
You can also press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run window.

Comment: nothing - VS 2013 win 8

Comment: nothing. having the same problem for hours now